# React-router-dom doesn't redirect to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm at a loss. `react-router-dom` does not work for me. The application is not redrawn when changing the address in the url. For some time I looked for this error on the Internet and made sure that everything should work for me. Moreover, everything works on my last project with identical routing settings.

What I'm talking about.
I have two routes:

```
 <Route path="/" component={MainPage} />
 <Route path="/add" component={AddAdvertisementPage} />
```

My MainPage component is loaded by default, when I write `http://localhost:3000/add` in the search bar, the page is refreshed and I still stay on the `MainPage` component.
If I swap the components of the routes:

```
 <Route path="/" component={AddAdvertisementPage} />
 <Route path="/add" component={MainPage} />
```

In this case, the opposite is true. I will display the `AddAdvertisementPage` component in the `/route`, but will not display the `MainPage` in the `/add` route 
**My App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import AddAdvertisementPage from './Pages/AddAdvertisementPage';
import MainPage from './Pages/MainPage';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={AddAdvertisementPage} />
        <Route path="/add" component={MainPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**My index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**My package.json:**

```
 {
  "name": "map-project-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.2",
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.7.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-cropper": "^2.1.8",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-simple-image-slider": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the order of the routes in the `Switch` in `App`.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={AddAdvertisementPage} />
    <Route path="/add" component={MainPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

The `Switch` component renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location. `path="/"` matches all routes, so it's matched first and rendered. Inside the `Switch` path order and specificity matters! Order the routes from more specific paths to less specific paths.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/add" component={MainPage} />
    <Route path="/" component={AddAdvertisementPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```